# page number location in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer, page-numbering

I am using `\printbibliography` command to create bibliography in `biblatex`. The problem is the page number is located at the center bottom while i want it to be at the right bottom. I don't have the slightest how to modify it. I've tried modifying the environment but seems not to be the case. Anyone has an idea?

*edit*
here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,labelnumber,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibli.bib}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\cite{haber}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi allen, welcome to TeX.sx! It's always best (especially with a problem like this) to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that demonstrates the problem. The example should start from `\documentclass...` and contain only code that is necessary to demonstrate the problem. This saves others the work of having to reproduce an example, and it helps to narrow down the problem.

Comment: What are you using to get it at the right bottom for the rest of your document? Can you post a minimal example that shows how you are making the pagestyles?

Comment: oops..wrong post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put

```
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \thispagestyle{fancy}
```

right after the `\printbibliography` command.

Answer (score 1):

I just notice that the above solution only solves the issue for the last page of bibliography. For all pages, the following code is suggested

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}
```